# disable button click of all listview item when choice_mode is on

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Am using `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` for a `ListView` and it is working fine. problem is my `ListView` row item contains 2 buttons. And i want this all row buttons set to be disable when i have some rows checked.How to achieve this?

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            final int checkedCount = studentListView.getCheckedItemCount();
            mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " selected");
            adapter.toggleSelection(position);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            SparseBooleanArray selected;
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.menu_item1:

                    mode.finish();
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_item2:

                    mode.finish();
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_item3:

                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.multiselectmenu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            adapter.removeSelection();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Add one boolean in your model class and check same condition in adapter

```
        raw_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (<booleanvar==true>) {
                    // 
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try it once and let me know your review or find any problem..!

Comment: But i want to disable buttons of all row view. and args1 will return only current seected view.

Comment: check edited answer you need to add boolean flag to check rather particular raw button need to enable or not

Comment: check condtion e.g - if(arraylist.get(position).booleanvar){ }

Comment: i thought about this. But my list may contains 1000 of entries. so is it good practice to check every time for boolean value? Actually am looking for any inbuild method like listView.setItemsCanFocus(false). but its not working

Comment: That's the only way i can suggest you , But must try it once If you want so , else find another solution and let me know if its helpful :)

Comment: your suggestion is also correct. so i will mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Check when have some rows checked.

Call buton.setEnabled(false) for button you want to disable.

Comment: but i want all row buttons should be non clickable